# How to get Electron + rxdb to work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I want to learn and develop a desktop app by using electron + rxdb.

My file structure:

- main.js (the main process of electron)
- /js-server/db.js (all about rxdb database, include creation)
- /js-client/ui.js (renderer process of electron)
- index.html (html home page)

**main.js code**:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const dbjs = require('./js-server/db.js')
const {ipcMain} = require('electron')
ipcMain.on('search-person', (event, userInput) => {
  event.returnValue = dbjs.searchPerson(userInput);
})
```

**db.js code:**

```
var rxdb = require('rxdb');
var rxjs = require('rxjs');
rxdb.plugin(require('pouchdb-adapter-idb'));
const personSchema = {
    title: 'person schema',
    description: 'describes a single person',
    version: 0,
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
        Name: {type: 'string',primary: true},
        Age: {type: 'string'},
    },
    required: ['Age']
};
var pdb;
rxdb.create({
    name: 'persondb',
    password: '123456789',
    adapter: 'idb',
    multiInstance: false
}).then(function(db) {
    pdb = db;
    return pdb.collection({name: 'persons', schema: personSchema})
});

function searchPerson(userInput) {
    pdb.persons.findOne().where('Name').eq(userInput)
    .exec().then(function(doc){return doc.Age});
}
module.exports = {
    searchPerson: searchPerson
}
```

**ui.js code:**

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');
function getFormValue() {
    let userInput = document.getElementById('searchbox').value;
    displayResults(ipcRenderer.sendSync("search-person",userInput));
    document.getElementById('searchbox').value = "";
}
```

Whenever I run this app, I got these errors:

1. (node:6084) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: RxError:
   RxDatabase.create(): Adapter not added. (I am sure I've installed the pouched-adapter-idb module successfully)
2. Type error, cannot read property "persons" of undefined. (this error pops out when I search and hit enter to the form in index.html)

I am new to programming, especially js, I've been stuck on these errors for a week, just can't get it to work. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that this line is in main.js:

```
const dbjs = require('./js-server/db.js')
```

Why? Because you're requiring `RxDB` inside the main process and using the IndexedDB adapter. IndexedDB is a browser API and thus can only be used in a rendering process. In Electron, the main process is a pure Node/Electron environment with no access to the Chromium API's.

## Option #1

If you want to keep your database in a separate thread then consider spawning a new hidden browser window:

```
import {BrowserWindow} from 'electron'
const dbWindow = new BrowserWindow({..., show: false})
```

And then use IPC to communicate between the two windows similarly to how you have already done.

## Option #2

Use a levelDB adapter that only requires NodeJS API's so you can keep your database in the main process.